# ¿Por qué no se me abre ningún fichero?

Tags: c++

Tengo una duda con este código ya que no me lee ningún fichero y su función principal es esa.

`RUTA_RELATIVA`, es la ruta donde está los ficheros a leer:

```
void pedirNombreFichero(char nombreRelativo[]){
    strcat(nombreRelativo,RUTA_RELATIVA);
    cout<<"Escriba el nombre de un fichero de usos del sistema Bizi:  ";
    cin>>nombreRelativo;
}
```

Comment: Porque strcat no es para abrir acrchivos

Answer (score 1):

El strcat queda sin efecto tras el cin>>nombreRelativo;
Luego del cin deberías juntar el path al nombre de archivo ingresado.

En todo caso define una variable filename y el con es a este luego haces strcat;

```
    char filename[255]={0};
      cin>>filename;
     strcat(nombreRelativo,filename);
```

Ah, y lógicamente no hay ninguna instrucción para abrir archivo. Segun el nombre del metodo solo es para pedir nombre no abrir archivo y si el nombre lo devuelve mal como lo esta haciendo entonces quien quiera abrir el archivo no podrá hacerlo.

Comment: Ya puestos también habría que garantizar que `nombreRelativo` tiene espacio suficiente para almacenar el resultado de `strcat`